# What is the most pythonic way to sum columns in a panda when data is left in strings?

Tags: python, pandas

An example table is below.

I'm having trouble thinking of the most pythonic way of doing the following:

I want to calculate a sum such that we add the new column value if there is a value and add the current column value if there is not. From the example table below, I would want the agg_sum to be 1 + 5 - 2 = 4

One idea would be do do something like

`agg_sum = df.loc[df['new'] != '', 'new'].sum() + df.loc[df['new'] == '', 'current'].sum()`

But, the sum() gives a type error because the entries are not ints. I am purposely leaving them as strings because I will also be printing this df out and the dollar signs and the parentheses for the negative numbers make the table readable.

I know what you are thinking, make a second table where you change the entries to ints and use the code above, but here's the thing, i don't know how to do that pythonically either!

Thank you!

| current | new |
| --- | --- |
| ($100) | $1 |
| $5 |  |
| $100 | ($2) |

Comment: I would recommend you store numbers as numbers, not as strings. Then you can do math with your dataframe. This is the only way to work effectively with data. You only need to show formatted numbers when you are showing results to end users.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a possible solution :

```
rep = {"\(\$(\d+)\)": r"-\1", "\$": "", "": None}

num = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.replace(rep, regex=True)))

agg_sum = num["new"].where(num["new"].notna(), num["current"]).sum()

print(agg_sum) # 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to numbers using regular expression extraction and then `numpy.where` for conditional selection of values to sum up.

```
df['current_val'] = df['current'].str.extract('\(?\$(\d*)\)?')[0].astype('Int64') * df['current'].str.contains('\(').map({True: -1, False: 1})
df['new_val'] = df['new'].str.extract('\(?\$(\d*)\)?')[0].astype('Int64') * df['new'].str.contains('\(').map({True: -1, False: 1})

sum = np.where(df['new_val'].isnull(), df['current_val'], df['new_val']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep numbers as strings in your dataframe. Use real numbers so that you can do math with them directly, and instead use a [styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) (or other formatting mechanism) for display purposes. Suppose your dataframe is just numbers:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'current':[-100,5,100], 'new':[1,np.nan,-2]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   current  new
0     -100  1.0
1        5  NaN
2      100 -2.0
```

Now you can simply make the sum as:

```
agg_sum = df['new'].fillna(df['current']).sum()
print(agg_sum)
```

Output:

```
4.0
```

You can use a styler to make the output pretty. For example, this styler hides the index, formats numbers as required and sets all column widths to the passed width (defaulting to 10):

```
def make_pretty(styler, width=10):
    def width_formatter(width):
        return lambda v:f'{v:>{width}}'
    
    def dollar_formatter(width):
        def format_dollars(value):
            nonlocal width
            if np.isnan(value):
                v = ''
            elif value < 0:
                v = f'(${abs(value):.0f})'
            else:
                v = f'${value:.0f}'
            return f'{v:>{width}}'
        
        return format_dollars
    
    styler.hide()
    styler.format(dollar_formatter(width))
    styler.format_index(width_formatter(width), axis=1)
    return styler
```

You can use it like this:

```
print(df.style.pipe(make_pretty).to_string())
```

Output:

```
   current        new
    ($100)         $1
        $5
      $100       ($2)
```

Or specify a different width:

```
print(df.style.pipe(make_pretty, width=7).to_string())
```

Output:

```
current     new
 ($100)      $1
     $5
   $100    ($2)
```